# vue: access a specific array from an object inside an array

Tags: arrays, loops, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to show only one of the `questions` array in a single page, depending on which category the user picks.

```
faqData = [
  {
    name: "first-category",
    questions: [
      {
        id: 1,
        question: "First question?",
        answer: "First Answer"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        question: "Second question?",
        answer: "blablablabla"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "second-category",
    questions: [
      {
        id: 1,
        question: "First question?",
        answer: "First Answer"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        question: "Second question?",
        answer: "blablablabla"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "third-category",
    questions: [
      {
        id: 1,
        question: "First question?",
        answer: "First Answer"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

vue file

```
<div class="accordion" role="tablist" v-for="eachQuestion in questionList.questions" :key="eachQuestion.id">
    <FAQCollapses v-bind:eachQuestion="eachQuestion" />
</div>

//script
data () {
        return {
            questionList: faqData
        }
}
```

My template code shows a blank space and there's nothing in the console so I'm confused where the mistake is. The problem is I don't know how to specifically get only one category from the `faqData` array, depending on what category the user clicks. Can someone tell me what is the best practice to achieve my goal? I have read all the similar questions in StackOverflow but it didn't work in my case. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way (and a best practice, I guess), it to implement computed prop with name like, for example `selectedFaqQuestion`:

```
computed: {
    selectedFaqQuestion () {
        return selectedCategory ? this.faqData.find(category => category.name === this.selectedCategory).questions : []
    }
}
```

and use it into v-for:

```
<div v-for="eachQuestion in selectedFaqQuestion" :key="eachQuestion.id">
    <FAQCollapses v-bind:eachQuestion="eachQuestion" />
</div>
```

Of course, to do so, you need to implement new data prop `selectedCategory`, where you are going to store selected category, on user's click:

```
data () {
    return {
        questionList: faqData,
        selectedCategory: null
    }
}
```

So, as you mentioned, you need to handle user click, when going to see any questions based on selected category. To handle its click, you need to use `v-on:click`. To pass new value of selected category you need to update it: `selectedCategory = 'somecategoryname'`

`'somecategoryname'` means something from your faqData prop 'name', for example `first-category`:

```
<div> Please, peek FAQ category to show answers: 
  <span v-on:click="selectedCategory = 'first-category'"> First category </span>
  <span v-on:click="selectedCategory = 'second-category'"> Second category </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I really appreciate it. However, I have one question, I don't quite understand this part `v-on:click="selectedCategory = 'somecategoryname'"`, specifically the `'somecategoryname'`. What does this mean? Sorry, I'm kind of new to Vue..

Comment: thank you! i just edited my question though. anyway, if the user click is from a different page, does that mean i should store the value of selectedcategory using vuex?

Comment: Yes, it is. It is the most simple and right way to communicate two different pages.